# Should I still support a screen resolution of 1024x786 or can I ignore it and support 1280x720 and higher?

Tags: web-development, website-design, screen-size, resolution

Only for websites, not webapps.
There are not many computers left with 1024x786, so why still support it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That entirely depends on your user base, for a commercial site I work on 1024x768 represents 9.49% (166,453) of our visitors, we will continue to support that for some time.

The flip side to that, a hobby project that I work on has a different audience and I don't support 1024x768 as it only represents about 2%.

Check your existing stats and use that to make the decision. Failing that create a responsive layout and stop worrying about the resolution.

Comment: it's a commercial website but only 6% of the uses have 1024x768, guess I'll still support it then

Comment: +1 for responsive layout. Of course then you may have to start looking at browser _version_ stats instead of size to decide what CSS features you can use (IE <9 doesn't do media queries), but it's getting easier and better all the time.

Comment: also consider tablets - iPads are 1024x768, and are a small but rapidly growing market, owned by people with (generally) a higher disposable income.